# impact world and recipe 2016 in Brightway

Tags: brightway

Has somebody tried to implement the impact assessment methods *impact world+* [ref](http://www.impactworldplus.org/en/index.php) or *Recipe 2016* [ref](http://www.rivm.nl/en/Documents_and_publications/Common_and_Present/Newsmessages/2016/New_version_ReCiPe_2016_to_determine_environmental_impact) in Brightway?

The characterization factors of impact world + are available for download (beta version). The spreadsheet facilitates an implementation in Simapro but I guess that may cause some trouble if the biosphere flows are defined differently in Brightway2 and Simapro (is this the case?). I have not been able to find the characterisation factors for Recipe 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anyone has done this yet. I have started with the [regionalized characterization factors](https://github.com/cmutel/bw2-lcimpact), but these are not complete. ReCiPe factors [are here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11367-016-1246-y#SupplementaryMaterial).

SimaPro makes changes to biosphere flow names and other metadata, and additionally includes a number of biosphere flows that ecoinvent doesn't, so there is a compatibility problem with the default Brightway flows.

Matching is possible - not even all that hard - but enough of a pain that it would be great if someone would do this. Ecoinvent knows it is something that people are asking for, but my understanding is that it is not currently a priority.