# Is it possible to prevent modifications in the original Ecoinvent database in Brightway2 ? And impact world/Recipe 2016

Tags: brightway

Hello I have 2 questions:

First: Is there a way of preventing the users to make modifications in the original Ecoinvent database but still allowing changes in the copies or manually added activities ? When modelling LCA processes, often I unknowingly modify some values in the original version. As a result, sometimes I have to re-import the entire database and make activities again.

Second: Has anyone implemented the Recipe 2016 or impact world methods in Brightway yet ? I saw some discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787149/impact-world-and-recipe-2016-in-brightway), but could not find any other resources. Would make my life much easier. If not, what should be the most efficient way of doing this? Strarting from scratch in Brightway2 or exporting from Simapro ?

Comment: In general, separate questions should be posted separately :)

Comment: Thanks Chris, will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, there isn't. But it requires some work to make changes - you have to load an object from a background database, change it, then call `.save()`. I don't see how this could be a real problem, but maybe I am just missing it. The activity-browser treats every database as read-only, and also requires you to click an edit activity button to make any changes, that might be a solution for you?
2. You aren't the only one! I will create a repo with instructions on how to do this, and update my answer in the next few days.

Comment: Yes I agree it requires some work. The thing is when creating a new activity, I usually copy one and then use it. Recently, I didnt notice I deleted an original activity, which changed results of many other activities in the database. So I was just wondering this could be useful when I am working with people just starting with brightway.

Comment: One thing you could do is to always specify a new database when calling `Acitivty.copy()`, e.g. `Activity.copy(database="my new database")`. Just make sure the database already exists :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/laurepatou/IMPACT-World-in-Brightway.git Here you can download an implementation of Impact world + ... last time I used it the endpoint had a couple of duplicated flows so it needs some cleaning ;)

Answer (score 0):

For ImpactWorld+, I would rather use the official releases here: http://www.impactworldplus.org/en/download.php

There is a non-regionalized version specifically for Brighway2, and a regionalized version is being worked on.

Comment: Awesome ! I didn't know this exists :)

Comment: The official release redirects to a Zenodo site with the same packages as the Github repo mentioned by @Nabla, so I doubt there is a large difference :)

Comment: Ah, oops, sorry @Nabla